# Selenium Webdrive (Java) - generate variables with predefined part of the name

Tags: java, selenium

I have the loop below, where I am trying to create the variables dynamically :

```
for (int i=0; i<cnAmnt.size(); i++) {

            String groupId = "group_"+i;
            System.out.println("Id :"+groupId);

            List<WebElement> grAmount1 = Login.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#Change>#"+groupId+">li.Syst"));
            System.out.println("The amount is " + grAmount1.size());

        }
```

In the part :  `String groupId = "group_"+i;` I am trying to generate variables, but it's not that I want. Is is possible to generate as :

String groupId+i = "smth"; so that in the end I could get in my loop something like String groupId_0 =...., String groupId_1 .... etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String arr[]= new String[]{"smith1","smith2"};

            for (int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++) {
                String groupId = arr[i];
                System.out.println("Id :"+groupId);

            }
        }
```

Output

```
Id :smith1
Id :smith2
```

Create array then use that array to assign value to groupId.